# Avoiding use of global variable while allowing access to object owned by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, object-oriented-analysis

I am writing a Java program that utilizes two threads, one to iterate constantly over an ArrayList of widgets and update their states, the second is a thread utilizing swing to animate a series of blocks based on the state of the widgets.

My question is how can I get Painter, which implements the Runnable interface, to see the arraylist of widgets that WidgetManager owns? Moreover, is this pattern inherently faulty? I have been taught to avoid global variable (such as defining the WidgetList in main instead) but to my understanding, there is no way to pass a reference to a Runnable thread because the run() method requires no dependency injection.

```java
main{
  WidgetManager wm;
  Painter painter;
  painter.run();
  wm.updateWidgets();
}

public class WidgetManager{
  volatile ArrayList<Widget> widgets;

  void updateWidgets(){
    while(true){
      //do some stuff
    }
  }
}

public class Painter implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    //paint some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: in main: painter.setWidgets(wm.getWidgets());

Comment: Besides the possibility to provide `Painter` with a `setWidgets` method, you can also give it a constructor with parameters, receiving arbitrary things right on construction. The `Painter` implements `Runnable` to define the contract for the `Thread` class. That doesn’t mean that your application can’t use `Painter` like an instance of `Painter`—a class under your control. But besides that, your approach won’t work. Declaring the field holding a reference to an `ArrayList` as `volatile`, doesn’t magically make the `ArrayList` (and the way you’re using it) thread safe.

Comment: Thank you @Holger for the input on the thread-safety issue.  I'm still trying to learn about multithreading, so it's useful to know when I don't know something. Do you have any particular resources/key terms you would recommend I look into for maintaining thread safety for this sort of operation? I was originally thinking about using some sort of locking, but I figure that locking the array any time the painter went over it would be essentially the same thing as not multithreading at all.

Comment: Locking during painting doesn’t have to be that bad. It depends on how often the list is updated and how long the updates take. In other words, it depends on how high the chances are that the locking actually leads to blocking. If updates happen too often to make locking feasible, performing updates on a different list and exchanging the lists after completion might be the better choice. “Java Concurrency in Practice”, [ISBN:978-0321349606](https://www.google.com/search?q=978-0321349606&) might be a helpful read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the `run()` method requires no [arguments]

The `run()` method is defined by an `interface`. You can create your thread using an instance of any class that `implements` (note, not `extends`) the interface. Your class can have instance variables...

```
public class Painter implements Runnable{
  private ArrayList<Widget> widgets;
  public Painter(ArrayList<Widget> widgets) {
      this.widgets = widgets;
  }
  public void run(){
     paintSomeStuffBasedOnContentOf(widgets);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! A question: would this implementation not result in WidgetPainter receiving a single copy of the widgets array that existed at the time of WidgetPainter's instantiation? Meaning, as I WidgetManager updates the widgets, WidgetPainter would not see those updates?

Comment: You asked, "...access to object owned by another thread," So I did not write any code that would copy the array. In order to use the `Painter` version from my example, you'll have to pass a reference to an `ArrayList<Widget>` object when you call the constructor. The new painter object then will keep its own reference to _the same_ ArrayList.